# How to write make rules for a series of similar compiles?

Tags: makefile

In my project i need to compile a series of c++ files into so-files.

For each file i have to do this:

```
XXXWrapper.o: XXXWrapper.cpp XXXWrapper.h
    $(CC) $(COPT) $(INCL) -fPIC

XXXWrapper.so:XXXWrapper.o
$(CC) -shared  -o XXX.so XXXWrapper.o \
    $(POPS)/XXX.o -lhdf5 \
    -L$(KERNEL) -lKernel \
    -L$(COMMON) -lCommon
```

Here `$(INCL)` contains all necessary includes, and

```
COPT=-c $< -I $(COMMON) -o $@ $(CADD) $(CFLAGS)
```

In order to avoid repeating the same rules 40 times with only small variations, i tried this:

```
%Wrapper.o: %Wrapper.cpp %Wrapper.h  
    $(CC) $(COPT) $(INCL) -fPIC

%Wrapper.so: %Wrapper.o
    $(CC) -shared  -o $(subst,"Wrapper","",$@).so  $< \
    $(POPS)/$(subst,"Wrapper","",$@) -lhdf5 \
    -L$(KERNEL) -lKernel \
    -L$(COMMON) -lCommon
```

hoping that `$(subst,"Wrapper","",$@)` would return the part of the input filename before "Wrapper".
While the first rule worked well, result of the substitution was empty in the second rule:

```
~/utils/cgcc -c XXXWrapper.cpp -I ../common -o XXXWrapper.o -g -Wall  
-I../common -I../kernel -I../icosa -I../populations -I../genes -I../io -I../modular" -fPIC

~/utils/cgcc -shared  -o .so  XXXWrapper.o \
    ../populations/.o -lhdf5 \
-L../kernel -lKernel \
-L../common -lCommon
```

(note the `-o .so` and the `../populations/.o`)
Even if this had worked, the outputfile would have been named `XXX.o.so`, but i could have lived with this.

So I guess this means the substitution command can't be used like this.

Is there a way to achieve what i have in mind?

Comment: Maybe by using a modern day build system?

Answer (score 1):

First, this is wrong:

```
$(subst,"Wrapper","",$@)
```

Besides the fact that there should be no comma after `subst`, quotes are not special to make; this is substituting the literal string `"Wrapper"` with the literal string `""` (including quotes).  Since there is no string `"Wrapper"` in your target, this does nothing.

Second, it sounds to me like you just want `$*.so` which would be a lot easier.

Lastly, it's almost always wrong to create an output file that is different than the one you told make you would create.  I can only assume you have some obscure and compelling reason to want to do this...

Comment: thanks for correcting my susbst expression - now it works. Regarding your  last point: now that you mention it, there is no real reason why the output file needs a different name.